# Using IF THEN in Access 2010 Query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm not very knowledgeable in coding of Access queries, so I hope someone can help with this issue.
I have a query (using the query builder) that has a field named `RetrainInterval` from table `tblProcedures` (this will return a number like 1, 3, 6, 12, etc.; the rotational months the particular document have to be retrained on) and another field named `Training/Qualification Date` from table `tblTrainingRecords`.

I want the query to look at the `RetrainInterval` for a given record (record field is `ClassID` in `tblProcedures`) and then look at the `Training/Qualification Date` and calculate if that record should be in the query.

In a module I would do this:

```
IF RetrainInterval = 1 Then
DateAdd("m",1,[Training/Qualification Date]) <add to query if <=today()+30>
ElseIf RetrainInterval = 3 Then
DateAdd("m",3,[Training/Qualification Date]) <add to query if <=today()+30>
ElseIF......
```

How can I translate this into something that would work in a query? My end goal is to generate a report that will show me what document class numbers are due within a specified time interval (say I enter 30 in the form textbox to represent any upcoming required training within 30 days of the query), but all of the calculations to determine this is based off of when the last training date was (stored in the training records table). I also want to make sure that I do not get multiple returns for the same class number since there will be multiple training entries for each class, just grab the minimum last training date. I hope I explained it well enough. It's hard to put this into words on what I am trying to do without positing up the entire database.

***UPDATE***

I think I have simplified this a bit after getting some rest. Here are two images, one is the current query, and one is what comes up in the report. I have been able to refine this a bit, but now my problem is I only want the particular Class to show once on the report, not twice, even though I have multiple retrain due dates (because everything is looking at the table that holds the employee training data and will have multiple training's for each Class number). I would like to only show one date, the oldest. Hope that makes sense.

Query - http://postimg.org/image/cpcn998zx/

Report - http://postimg.org/image/krl5945l9/

Comment: Use "begin...... end"  instead of "then"

Comment: If you are wanting to do that in-line with your query, have a look at the `IIF()` function. alternatively if you want some help cobbling something together, give us some sample data and what you would expect the output to look like with that data and we can see what we can do.

Comment: Your design worries me a bit, could you show the current Query you use without the criteria.

Comment: You can also write methods in a module then use them in your query

Answer (score 2):

When *RetrainInterval* = 1, you add 1 month to *[Training/Qualification Date]*.

When *RetrainInterval* = 3, you add 3 months to *[Training/Qualification Date]*.

And so on.

The pattern appears to be that *RetrainInterval* is the number of months to add.  If that is true, use *RetrainInterval* directly in your `DateAdd()` expression and don't bother about `IF THEN`.

```
DateAdd("m", RetrainInterval, [Training/Qualification Date])
```

Comment: I had this suggestion up my sleeve, but was not sure, as the `tblTrainingRecords` seems to be on the many side of the relationship and there might be a need for selecting the most recent record **AND** the fact most dates will be < Date()+30

Comment: I couldn't understand the full context to save my life.  I will delete this answer if it proves useless.

Comment: No @HansUp this is the right solution, I was just curious if what I thought was something that has been overlooked.

Comment: Yes, I suspect there is more involved, but I don't see how we can reasonably expect to figure out what that is given the current state of the question.  If you can do it, more power to you.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp, see my update in my original post. Hopefully I am on the right track...?

Comment: I'm lost and confused.  I thought this was about `IF THEN` logic.  And perhaps it started out that way.  But, best I can tell, your issue is now about consolidating 2 rows into one.  If that is true, save the query you have now and use that as the data source for a new query where you `GROUP BY` all the columns except the last one and take the `Min()` of that *Retrain Due Date* field.  Does that get you what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @HansUp, You are correct, it did start out as an `IF THEN`, but I thought I would try something different. I just tried your recommendation of the `GROUP BY` and using `MIN()`. When I run the report, I get an "Enter Parameter Value"  message and wanting me to enter the Retrain Due Date.

Comment: Probably your `GROUP BY` query output does not include a *Retrain Due Date* column.  Access gave your `Min([Retrain Due Date])` field expression some other name.  Open the query in SQL or Datasheet View and find out the name Access assigned.  Then revise the report to look for that name instead of *Retrain Due Date*.

Comment: That did the trick. It must have changed when I redid the query and forgot to update the report. Now the system is working just as I wanted it to.

Comment: That's good news.  Please submit an answer which describes your solution and accept that answer when the system allows you to do so.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that in a query. Been there, cursed that!

You can use the IFF( 2>x ; 1 ;0)
Giving that if the first statement is true, 1 is returned, and 0 if false.
You can not return a criteria like IFF(2>x ; Cell>2 ; Cell>0) (Not possible) It will just return 0 if you try, i think. it will not give an error all the time.

You have to use criterias!
I would to something like this picture:
[image: Example]

I hope you follow, else let me know.